# DTCoreText images aren't display

Tags: ios, objective-c, dtcoretext

I use `DTCoreText` for HTML-document rendering in iOS. I notice that some of the images aren't displayed. These images have relative url in the `src`. When I changed the `src` value to filename and placed image to the same folder as for html-document all images were displayed. Do relative links work in the `DTCoreText` or I need to rebuild all URLs?

Answer (score 2):

Using `NSBaseURLDocumentOption` option for creating `DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder` fixes the problem:

```
NSDictionary *builderOptions = @{
                                 DTDefaultFontFamily:@"Helvetica",
                                 NSBaseURLDocumentOption:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:YES]
                                 };

DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder *stringBuilder = [[DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder alloc] initWithHTML:htmlData options:builderOptions documentAttributes:nil];
```